# Job does not write to CSV or print row from scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data and  write to a csv in the below code.  As far as I can tell Selenium tends to print all the elements except for it does not seem to print the row or write to CSV.  I’ve had this issue in the past though generally this was easily addressed by re-writing the job.  I am using windows.  Unfortunately I do not know why it is doing this as the job works functionally otherwise.

My code below is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    os.remove('vtg121.csv')
except OSError:
    pass

driver.get('https://www.topbetta.com.au/sports/football/')

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

time.sleep(1)

url = "https://www.topbetta.com.au/sports/football/"
driver.get(url)

counter = 0
for link in range(len(wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/sports" and ./div[@class="name"]]'))))):
    wait(driver, 15).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mask")))
    link = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/sports" and ./div[@class="name"]]')))[counter]
    link.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    link = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//a[@href="/sports" and ./div[@class="name"]])[%s]' % str(counter + 1))))
    wait(driver, 15).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mask")))
    header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('header')
    header = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header)
    header = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_body-region"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]')
    header = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header)
    link.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="competition-events-module"]')))
    time.sleep(2)

    time.sleep(2)

    # link


    # Team ODDS
    langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".team-container.home div")
    langs_text = []

    for lang in langs:
        print(lang.text)
        langs_text.append(lang.text)

    time.sleep(0)

    # BACK TEAM
    #langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='runners']//li[2]")
    langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".home .price")
    langs1_text = []

    for lang in langs1:
        print(lang.text)
        langs1_text.append(lang.text)


    # Draw Odds
    #langs2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='runners']//li[1]")
    langs2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.draw.odds > div > a > span")
    langs2_text = []

    for lang in langs2:
        print(lang.text)
        langs2_text.append(lang.text)

    with open('vtg121.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in zip(langs_text, langs1_text, langs2_text):
            print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
    counter += 1
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Probably window specific issue let me test

Comment: I am unable to write to csv either.